# can it possible to use chat service without apns

Tags: ios, web-services, apple-push-notifications

I am using message chat service in my application by service request and response. But problem is that when sender sending message to receiver end receiver did'nt get any notification about the send message.

Just tell me what is the best option to respond the notification to the receiver.
Can it possible without using apple push notification service.

Comment: Please give additional information about your setup. As you said you are using request/response to get messages like heartbeat, it will not be real time messaging. For real time messaging you should use persistent connections to server so when ever new message is available on server it will push it to client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**APNS is not for CHAT**  Use [XMPP](http://xmpp.org/) or [MQTT](http://mqtt.org/). for both you will require a server side implementation.
For XMPP you can use use XMPPFramework. and for MQTT you can use Mosquito.

Answer (score 3):

Adding my answers below if someone comes later with the exact same question.

If app is in foreground and user is doing live chatting you can use any of the lightweight messaging protocol(like MQTT/XMPP) to notify about new message. In this case better to put message as a payload itself for instant messaging.

For reference you can check out sample code [here](https://github.com/AppLozic/Applozic-iOS-SDK/tree/master/sample-with-framework/Applozic) how to do it with MQTT.

But you should debug why your notification is not working. There are few checkpoints I can see:

1) Check your device tokenId you are storing on your application server.(In case of APNS it should be of 64 char length).

2) Check if push notification is enabled for you application in [apple developer member center.](https://developer.apple.com/membercenter/index.action)

3) Check your SSL certificate used by your application server is proper. here is the simple step by step guide to get SSL cert.

https://blog.applozic.com/get-your-apple-push-ssl-certificate-abebf1edb338#.v7xu5cn0k

4) Make sure your code signing cert type is matching with apple push SSL certificate.Like if you are signing your code with developer certificate, apple push ssl cert should be of development one (not distribution).

Hope this might help others.

Answer (score 0):

first you have to seen the all properties of the push notification like token id is right or not. is your appid enable the push notification service or not.